# How to indent a long sentence in an algorithm

Tags: indentation, algorithmicx, algorithmic

[image]

In this algorithm format I want the the "Considering the jth...." to be having the same indentation throughout even in newline.

The Code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{hello}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{ASAPP}{}
\State $\textit{i} \gets \text{0}$, $\textit{j} \gets \text{0}$, $\textit{k} \gets \text{0}$
\While {i $\leq$ nom}
\While {j $\leq C_{i}$}
\State Considering the \textit{j}th edge of the \textit{i}th metabolite, \textit{x} and \textit{y} contains the vertices of the \textit{j}th edge
\State $\textit{k} \gets \text{\textit{j} + 1}$
\While { k $\leq C_{i}$}
\State Considering the \textit{k}th edge of the \textit{i}th metabolite, \textit{x1} and \textit{y1} contains the vertices of the \textit{k}th edge.
\EndWhile
\EndWhile
\EndWhile
\BState \emph{top}:
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a 1-time fix, or is this problem something that will have to be addressed many times in your document?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) to figure out the width of a box that would fit until the end of the line:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,algorithm,tabularx}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\multiline}[1]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\ALG@thistlm}[t]{@{}X@{}}
    #1
  \end{tabularx}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{hello}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{ASAPP}{}
      \State $i \gets 0$, $j \gets 0$, $k \gets 0$
      \While { $i \leq \text{nom}$ }
        \While {$j \leq C_i$ }
          \State \multiline{%
            Considering the $j$-th edge of the $i$-th metabolite,~$x$ and~$y$ 
            contains the vertices of the $j$-th edge}
          \State $k \gets j + 1$
          \While { $k \leq C_i$ }
            \State \multiline{%
              Considering the $k$-th edge of the $i$-th metabolite,~$x_1$ and~$y_1$ 
              contains the vertices of the $k$-th edge.}
          \EndWhile
        \EndWhile
      \EndWhile
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

`\multiline{<stuff>}` sets its contents in a `tabularx` that is aligned at the `[t]`op inside an `X`-column. The width of this column is the difference of a regular `\linewidth` minus the current algorithm line indent.

Answer (score 2):

If one can live with manual line-breaking, then a `\Longunderstack[l]{}` is an option

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{hello}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{ASAPP}{}
\State $\textit{i} \gets \text{0}$, $\textit{j} \gets \text{0}$, 
  $\textit{k} \gets \text{0}$
\While {i $\leq$ nom}
\While {j $\leq C_{i}$}
\State \Longunderstack[l]{Considering the \textit{j}th edge of the
   \textit{i}th metabolite, \textit{x} and \textit{y}\\ 
  contains the vertices of the \textit{j}th edge}
\State $\textit{k} \gets \text{\textit{j} + 1}$
\While { k $\leq C_{i}$}
\State \Longunderstack[l]{Considering the \textit{k}th edge of the 
   \textit{i}th metabolite, \textit{x1} and \textit{y1}\\ 
  contains the vertices of the \textit{k}th edge.}
\EndWhile
\EndWhile
\EndWhile
\BState \emph{top}:
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]