# Indent at automatically generated line breaks is lost for long single statements in algorithm

Tags: indentation, algorithms, algpseudocode

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[h!]
\caption{xxx} 
\label{alg:a_star}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State start 
        \While{$O \neq \emptyset$}
            \State very loooooooooooong, long, long, long ,long ,long ,long ,long, long ,long, long ,long   ,long,long, long, long ,long ,long ,long ,long, long ,long, long ,long ,long, long, long ,long, long long long statement
        \EndWhile
        \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

How can I use 'algpseudocode' and keep the indent when automatically a new line is used? I already tried the solutions from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69728/indenting-lines-of-code-in-algorithm) but without success.

Comment: Did you look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314023/how-to-indent-a-long-sentence-in-an-algorithm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly changed @Wrner's answer on [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314023/%E2%80%A6) and adopted to your MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\makeatletter
\newcommand\multiline[1]{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\ALG@thistlm}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[h!]
\caption{xxx}
\label{alg:a_star}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State start
        \While{$O \neq \emptyset$}
            \State\multiline{ very loooooooooooong, long, long, long ,long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long statement}
        \EndWhile
        \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]

**Edit:** For more vertical space after `\parbox`you can add to definition of`\multiline` command `\strut` (as pointed @Johannes Z) or `\smallskip˙`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\multiline[1]{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\ALG@thistlm}{#1\smallskip}}  % or \strut
\makeatother
```

Considering this change result of MWE is:

[image]

Comment: This makes the vertical space between the last line of `\multiline` and `\EndWhile` too small. Changing definition of `\multiline` to `\parbox[t]{...}{#1\strut}` will fix this, as suggested in https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15251 .

Comment: @JohannesZ, indeed, vertical space can be increase by `\strut` or by `\smallskip`. Added to answer.

Comment: There are differences. `\smallskip` always adds a font-size-independent amount (e.g., 3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt for class `article` with `10pt`) of vertical skip, while `\strut` inserts an invisible (means zero-width) box with font-size-dependent dimensions (0.7em height and 0.3em depth). They differ in a) whether font-size-dependent and b) whether "always take effect" (since if the last line has height and depth both larger than that of a `\strut`, then `\strut` has no visual effects).